# Insert an image base 64 on excel using xlwt

Tags: python, image, base64, xlwt

Hello i am workin in odoo and this save all the images like base64 on the database. I have the code, but I am making an excel report where I need to put the image, the excel driver is xlwt, but i can't find a nice method.

```
image = product_id.image_smal (this is a base64)
```

On the web i found this:

```
xlwt.insert_bitmap('PATH', row, col)
```

and this:

```
fh = open("imageToSave.png", "wb")
fh.write(imgData.decode('base64'))
fh.close()
```

I can save the image but is not inserted and give me this error:

```
bitmap doesn't appear to to be a valid bitmap image.
```

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to convert png to bmp you need to:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("imageToSave.png")
r, g, b, a = img.split()
img = Image.merge("RGB", (r, g, b))
img.save('imagetoadd.bmp')
xlwt.insert_bitmap('imagetoadd.bmp', row, col)
```

Hope this help!!