# Insert image using xlwt Python Odoo?

Tags: python, excel, image, odoo, xlwt

I am using Odoo 10. And I am trying to insert logo image in excel sheet using xlwt library. I tried the solution from the following link but it is not working for me.

[Insert an image base 64 on excel using xlwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172944/insert-an-image-base-64-on-excel-using-xlwt)

My code:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("/my_module/static/description/logo.png")
r, g, b, a = img.split()
img = Image.merge("RGB", (r, g, b))
img.save('imagetoadd.bmp')
xlwt.insert_bitmap('imagetoadd.bmp', 0, 0)
```

Error:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/my_module/static/description/logo.png'

I have double checked my path and spellings are correct and I have restarted the server, upgraded too.

When I give full path like this:
/home/username/folder/custom-addons/my_module/static/description/logo.png
I get the following error:
ValueError: need more than 3 values to unpack

Please help how can I achieve this inserting image into excel sheet using xlwt. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `ValueError: need more than 3 values to unpack` error is probably happening because `img.split()` is returning a tuple of less than 4 items, while you are `unpacking` to 4 variables, `r g b a`. Check the length of `img.split()` return and assign to variable accordingly, or use indexing to access first 3 elements, like

```
image_parts = img.split()
r = image_parts[0]
g = image_parts[1]
b = image_parts[2]
```

Update:

```
from PIL import Image
import xlsxwriter
from io import BytesIO

workbook   = xlsxwriter.Workbook('filename.xlsx')
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet()
img = Image.open("/home/username/folder/custom-addons/my_module/static/description/logo.png")
image_parts = img.split()
r = image_parts[0]
g = image_parts[1]
b = image_parts[2]
img = Image.merge("RGB", (r, g, b))
fo = BytesIO()
img.save(fo, format='bmp')
worksheet1.insert_image('A1', 'python.png', {'image_data': fi})
workbook.close()
```

Okay I found required function in `xlwt` library from it's source code.

```
from PIL import Image
import xlwt
from io import BytesIO

workbook   = xlwt.Workbook()
worksheet1 = workbook.add_sheet('Test')
img = Image.open("/home/username/folder/custom-addons/my_module/static/description/logo.png")
image_parts = img.split()
r = image_parts[0]
g = image_parts[1]
b = image_parts[2]
img = Image.merge("RGB", (r, g, b))
fo = BytesIO()
img.save(fo, format='bmp')
worksheet1.insert_bitmap_data(fo.getvalue(),0,0)
workbook.save('filename.xls')
img.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I have applied the above solution and getting this error now: IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'imagetoadd.bmp'.   I have given full permissions to my module with chmod but still same permission error.

Comment: Because your current working directory of your python process is not your module path, but somewhere else. As in this problem, you don't really need persistent file but to insert in excel file, you should use BytesIO instead of a file name to save to, which will create required bitmap image in memory and you can call `insert_bitmap()` with that file.

Comment: Can you update the answer plz? as I dont know the proper syntax

Comment: is it not possible using xlwt? bcoz I need to change the full code for using xlsxwriter

Comment: can't find documentation for xlwt

Comment: Trying your last update and it gives me this error: AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'insert_bitmap_data'

Comment: are you using latest version version of `xlwt`?? i tested this code, working with no error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186441/discussion-between-arryph-and-user3606682).

Comment: Awesome awesome awesome!!! Many thanks and hope if people reach here they get both the solutions xlsxwriter and xlwt :)

Comment: I check with the xlwt using python3 but it is give me error of that IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: I got the error of tuple index out of range if I'm taking the solution with xlwt. does anyone know why it happing?